# WebView2 NewWindowRequested missing windowName from anchor of window.open()

Tags: .net, winforms, webview2

I've been working with the WebView2 for a few days now and I'm running into an issue where I need to open a new window for specific URLs.

The preferred way is to have the triggers in the HTML using anchor targets or `window.open()` function but I'm not finding a way to get the actual windows name in the NewWindowRequested event.

This event does have a set of WindowFeatures which represents the WindowFeatures from the `window.open()` JavaScript function but does not contain the window name.

anyone have any tips for me?

Comment: Set `e.Handled = true` and provide a new CoreWebView2 Window, then set the `NewWindow` property. The `WindowFeatures` object can be used to define properties of the new Window.

Answer (score 2):

The NewWindowRequested event is raised after WebView2 applies the logic for the window name. That is, if the window name is for an existing window, that existing window will be navigated rather than raising the NewWindowRequested event. So for most situations you shouldn't need the window name.

If you need the window name for a different reason, like a side channel to provide extra information from your web content to your NewWindowRequested event handler, we are currently adding the Name property to the NewWindowRequested event args and you may see it as an experimental API in a future prerelease WebView2 nuget package. ([Spec](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/blob/master/specs/ExtendedNewWindowRequested.md))

Comment: Hi David. I think this is the answer that i was looking for. I do need the name for our requirements because we managed allowed windows from code (whitelisting of urls with allowed windows) but do use html event to determine if a windows is initialized in the first place. Currenty we keep track using the url as a workaround.

Comment: I think i need to wait for this Name property to be added to the API. When is this expected to be included in the release?

Comment: Not positive exactly when. Perhaps the next prerelease nuget package could contain it as an experimental API.